# dummy docker container for benchmarking

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dcos

I'm benchmarking a tool that monitors docker containers. To do that I need to launch several dummy containers with an orchestration tool such Kubernetes. The containers should be lightweight and shouldn't take any of the machine resources (e.g. ports), since the idea is to run 15 or more of these dummy containers in each machine of a cluster. I don't care about what the container does as long as it keeps running as a daemon and I can monitor it for a long period of time.

Is there any Docker image that meets these requirements and that I can use straight out of the box?.

Comment: what should these containers do?

Comment: I edited the question. I don't care what it does as long as it keeps running as a daemon. I was using httpd:alpine before but now it reserves port 80 so I can't launch more than one in the same machine

Comment: You can launch all the web servers you want as long as you aren't publishing the port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just run an alpine container with a sleep command.

Something like this:

`docker run -d alpine sh -c 'while sleep 3600; do :; done'`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is more than a year old but I found [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/luca3m/sleep) ([source](https://github.com/luca3m/app-examples/tree/master/sleep)) from [luca3m](https://luca3m.me/) that may help others.